# specify filetype for FlashGet's download command with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider a web page with of links to files. [FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com/download.htm)'s normal operation is by right-clicking, and selecting from the context menu.

I want to make it easy to launch FlashGet, and make a selection of file type to my desired file type without downloading any other resources being linked to.

For example, my desired file type is .rar , and other links shown are .jpg, .php, and others.

I just want to click one "download" button/link to launch FlashGet, and have it download all links in the page to files of type .rar, or whatever the user chooses/selects.

Can this be done with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

Only possible way is to work with flashget's clipboard-detection and http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/clipboard-copy ...